# Invalid Credentials error when connecting to Exchange Web Service

Tags: python-3.x, oauth-2.0, exchange-server, exchangewebservices, exchangelib

I am trying to connect to the Exchange Web Service to get access to Outlook and Teams data using Exchangelib library in Python. I am following the below article,
https://github.com/ecederstrand/exchangelib/issues/747

Below is the code snippet,

```
from exchangelib import IMPERSONATION, Account, Credentials, OAuth2Credentials, \
    Configuration, OAUTH2, Identity

client_id='XXX'
client_secret='XXX'
tenant_id='XXX'
user= 'XXX@YYY.onmicrosoft.com'

credentials = OAuth2Credentials(
    client_id=client_id,
    client_secret=client_secret,
    tenant_id=tenant_id,
    identity=Identity(primary_smtp_address=user)
)
config = Configuration(
    credentials=credentials,
    auth_type=OAUTH2,
    service_endpoint="https://outlook.office365.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx",
)
account = Account(
    user,
    config=config,
    autodiscover=False,
    access_type=IMPERSONATION,
)
print(account.root.all().count())
```

**I have given all the credentials correctly still, I am getting an Invalid Credential error as below.**

```
    886     if response.status_code == 401 and protocol.retry_policy.fail_fast:
    887         # This is a login failure
--> 888         raise UnauthorizedError('Invalid credentials for %s' % response.url)
    889     if 'TimeoutException' in response.headers:
    890         raise response.headers['TimeoutException']

UnauthorizedError: Invalid credentials for https://outlook.office365.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx
```

Any solution is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure that your user has permissions to access EWS? Also, exchangelib is not able to access Teams. You have to use the Graph API for that.

Comment: Yes, the user has the permissions to access EWS. I am looking to get outlook mail access through EWS. Could you share any resource for using Graph API? @ErikCederstrand

Comment: I have confirmation by other users that OAuth works with exchangelib (the code was contributed by an OAuth user) so there must be some problem with your tokens. I haven't worked with the Graph API, so I'm afraid I can't help you there.

Answer (score 0):

Having the same problem exactly as described above and with auto-discovery on I'm getting: `ErrorNonExistentMailbox: The SMTP address has no mailbox associated with it` but it seems that's expected if you don't use impersonation.